# javascript class finding elements based on a keyword in id, class, href or name

Tags: javascript

I made a class so that I can find specific elements based on a keyword in the elements id, class, name, or href. If a match is found it then gets pushed to an array. I managed to get this working on its own, but when I made it into a class it does not push any elements to the array. It seems to work to a degree because it finds all the `a` elements but it just doesnt match on keywords. What seems to be wrong here?

**HTML**

```
<a href="linka.html" id="poll-answer-8234" class="ca" name="poll_430" value="8234">
<a href="linka.html" id="poll-answer-9234" class="ca" name="poll_430" value="9234">  
<a href="linkb.html" id="survey-answer-7866" class="cb" name="poll_430" value="7866">
<a href="linkb.html" id="survey-answer-8998" class="cb" name="poll_430" value="8998">
<a href="linkc.html" id="quiz-answer-7866" class="cc" name="poll_430" value="7866">
<a href="linkc.html" id="quiz-answer-8998" class="cc" name="poll_430" value="8998">
```

**JS**

```
function nodeBulder(parameters) {
    this.selecter = parameters.selecter;
    this.targets = [];
    this.nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(parameters.tag);
    this.keyword = parameters.keyword;
    this.build = function () {
        switch (this.selecter) {
            case "byid":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].id.indexOf(this.keyword);
          console.log(node);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "byname":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].name.indexOf(this.keyword);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "byclass":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].className.indexOf(this.keyword);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "byhref":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].href.indexOf(this.keyword);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    this.random = function () {
        return this.targets[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.targets.length)];
    }
}

var idTest = new nodeBulder({ selecter: "byid", tag: 'a', keyword: 'poll-answer' });
var classTest = new nodeBulder({ selecter: "byclass", tag: 'a', keyword: 'cc' });

console.log(idTest.targets);
console.log(classTest.targets);
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, you are not calling the build method.

```
function nodeBulder(parameters) {
    this.selecter = parameters.selecter;
    this.targets = [];
    this.nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(parameters.tag);
    this.keyword = parameters.keyword;
    this.build = function () {
        switch (this.selecter) {
            case "byid":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].id.indexOf(this.keyword);
          console.log(node);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "byname":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].name.indexOf(this.keyword);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "byclass":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].className.indexOf(this.keyword);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "byhref":
                var count, node;
                for (count = 0; count < this.nodes.length; count++) {
                    node = this.nodes[count].href.indexOf(this.keyword);
                    if (node === 0) {
                        this.targets.push(this.nodes[count]);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    this.random = function () {
        return this.targets[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.targets.length)];
    }
}

var idTest = new nodeBulder({ selecter: "byid", tag: 'a', keyword: 'poll-answer' });
idTest.build();
var classTest = new nodeBulder({ selecter: "byclass", tag: 'a', keyword: 'cc' });
classTest.build();

console.log(idTest.targets);
console.log(classTest.targets);
```

Check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uz8wQ/)

Comment: Ah! right, its a function haha. Thank you for looking it over.

Comment: MAN nice I found that out too good job i upvoted.